# convert check mark "02713" UNIcode sign to String

Tags: java, string

I know how to convet a simple ASCII code number to a String

```
int ascii = 112;      
String sign = Character.toString((char)ascii);
```

but what about if I want to convert check mark  how can I do it?

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/isopub.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number is in hexadecimal so you need

```
int ascii = 0x2713;
```

or

```
int ascii = 10003;
```

see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

Answer (score 9):

You can write the four-digit hex code in a String literal, prefixed by `\u`:

```
"\u2713"
```

Or, indeed, just use the character directly in the String, since Java source code is interpreted [as unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1):

```
"✓"
```

Comment: Actually, I find in Windows 7 (US version) that source files are assumed to be windows-1252, unless I explicitly specify `javac -encoding UTF-8`.

Comment: @VGR [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1) says "Programs are written using the Unicode character set." So, if you are writing them in windows-1252, you may get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The language uses Unicode, but the file encoding determines how the source represents Unicode characters.  (Obviously `\u` always works regardless.)  [The documentation for javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) states: “**-encoding *encoding*** Sets the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If the -encoding option is not specified, then the platform default converter is used.”